# Logical task about children

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

A family has 5 children. Their ages: 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8 years old. Their names: Rose, Becca, Iona, Stu, Rob. Each of them has a talent: piano, math, violin, literature, computer.
I need to find out each child's age and talent, if the following facts are known:

1. Becca is 4 years old and doesn't know math.
2. A child, who know computer very well is one year older than Stu
3. A 7 years old child plays violin
4. Iona is not 8 years old
5. Rob is 5 years old and he's younger then a child whose talent is literature

I have an example solution, but it doesn't work, because I use Swi-prolog and it has some other syntax:

```
    domains
  ID= symbol
  Age = h(ID,NO)  
  HLIST  = reference Age*    
  NO = integer      
  NOLIST = NO*
predicates
  nondeterm solve
  nondeterm candidate(HLIST,HLIST)
  nondeterm perm(HLIST)
  nondeterm permutation(NOLIST,NOLIST)
  nondeterm delete(NO,NOLIST,NOLIST)
  member(Age,HLIST)
clauses
  solve():- candidate(Talents,Names),
    member(h(Becca,4),Names),member(h(maths,mathsA),Talents),mathsA<>4,
    member(h(Stu,StuA),Names),member(h(computer,compA),Talents),compA=StuA+1,
    member(h(violin,7),Talents),member(h(Iona,IonaA),Names),IonaA<>8,
    member(h(Rob,5),Names),member(h(literature,literatureA),Talents),literatureA>5,
    member(h(piano,_pianoA),Talents),member(h(Rose,RoseA),Names),
    member(h(BeccaT,4),Talents),member(h(StuT,StuA),Talents),
    member(h(IonaT,IonaA),Talents),member(h(RobT,5),Talents),
    member(h(RoseT,RoseA),Talents),write("Becca - 4 - ",BeccaT),nl,
    write("Stu - ",StuA," - ",StuT),nl,
    write("Iona - ",IonaA," - ",IonaT),nl,
    write("Rob - 5 - ",RobT),nl,
    write("Rose - ",RoseA," - ",RoseT),nl.

  candidate(L1,L2):- perm(L1),perm(L2).

  perm([h(_,A),h(_,B),h(_,C),h(_,D),h(_,E)]):- permutation([A,B,C,D,E],[4,5,6,7,8]). 

  permutation([],[]).
  permutation([A|X],Y):-delete(A,Y,Y1),permutation(X,Y1).

  delete(A,[A|X],X).
  delete(A,[B|X],[B|Y]):-delete(A,X,Y).

  member(A,[A|_]):-!.
  member(A,[_|X]):-member(A,X).
goal solve.
```

**I need to write this or other solution for Swi-Prolog.**

I wrote a code, but I got the "false" result. Where did I make mistakes?

```
puzzle(Children) :-
    Children = [child('Becca', 4, _), 
              child('Rob', 5, _), 
              child(_, 6, _), 
              child(_, 7, 'Violin'), 
              child(_, 8, _)],
    member(child('Rose', _, _), Children),
    member(child(_, _, 'Piano'), Children),
    member(child('Becca', AgeB, TalentB), Children),
    member(child(_, AgeM, 'Mathematics'), Children),
    member(child('Stu', AgeS, TalentS), Children),
    member(child(_, AgeC, 'Computer'), Children),
    member(child('Iona', AgeI, _), Children),
    member(child('Rob', AgeR, TalentR), Children),
    member(child(_, AgeL, 'Literature'), Children),
    TalentB \= 'Mathematics',
    AgeM > AgeB,
    AgeS + 1 = AgeC,
    AgeS < 8,
    TalentS \= 'Computer',
    AgeI < 8,
    AgeL > AgeR,
    TalentR \= 'Literature'.
```

Comment: See "zebra" at https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/puzzles

Comment: Answered at https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/i-cant-find-mistakes-in-my-code/5253